# How do I find my purchased OS X 10.9.2 which was accidentally deleted from App Store?

Tags: mac-appstore

I have accidentally deleted my copy of OS X Mavericks 10.9.2 from the App Store in the  purchased section under my account.

Is there any way I can get it back again without paying for a second time?

Comment: Paying for Mavericks a second time?

Comment: Well, you´ve asked and I answered. If my answer fits please accept the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

You can´t really delete your purchases - but you could hide purchases.

Apple has a [Support file](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4928) for this case.

You have to:

1. Open the Mac App Store.
2. Choose Store > Sign In, then enter your Apple ID and password.
3. Choose Store > View My Account.
4. Click on View Hidden Purchases from the Account Information page.
5. From the Hidden Purchases page, locate the app you would like to unhide.
6. Click the Unhide button.

Comment: Thank you very much i followed your instructions worked fine

Comment: @Simon If an answer has answered your question, you can mark it as the accepted solution.